# EPS32 switch from Arduino to IDF - need to find the corresponding BLE function

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32, arduino-esp32

I've a a working Arduino-code for my project and rewriting this in ESP-IDF.

For the following Arduino line I'm struggling to find the corresponding function for IDF.

```
static BLEUUID charUUID_tx("0000ff02-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
uint8_t reqBasicInfo[7] = {0xdd, 0xa5, 0x3, 0x0, 0xff, 0xfd, 0x77};
BLERemoteCharacteristic *pRemoteCharacteristicTX;
pRemoteCharacteristicTX->writeValue(reqBasicInfo, sizeof(reqBasicInfo));
```

Do I use `esp_ble_gattc_write_char` ? What has to be the handle? 0xff02?

Thank you for your input.

Comment: Read the [idf programming guide](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/), and idk [libraries/examples](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/tree/master/libraries).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct, you can use the [esp_ble_gattc_write_char](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/bluetooth/esp_gattc.html#_CPPv424esp_ble_gattc_write_char13esp_gatt_if_t8uint16_t8uint16_t8uint16_tP7uint8_t21esp_gatt_write_type_t19esp_gatt_auth_req_t)() function as it technically does what you need. However, this is a low level function for which you need to get the characteristic value handle, connection handle, etc. Below is code (copied from [here](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/issues/663)) that shows how this is done:-

```
case ESP_GATTC_GET_CHAR_EVT:
    if (p_data->get_char.status != ESP_GATT_OK) {
        break;
    }
    ESP_LOGI(GATTC_TAG, "GET CHAR: conn_id = %x, status %d", p_data->get_char.conn_id, p_data->get_char.status);
    ESP_LOGI(GATTC_TAG, "GET CHAR: srvc_id = %04x, char_id = %04x", p_data->get_char.srvc_id.id.uuid.uuid.uuid16, p_data->get_char.char_id.uuid.uuid.uuid16);

    if (p_data->get_char.char_id.uuid.uuid.uuid16 == 0xee01) {
        gl_profile_tab[PROFILE_A_APP_ID].char_id = p_data->get_char.char_id;

        uint8_t value[30];
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(value); ++i)
        {
            value[i] = i;
        }
        esp_ble_gattc_write_char(gattc_if,
                                conn_id,
                                &alert_service_id,
                                &gl_profile_tab[PROFILE_A_APP_ID].char_id,
                                sizeof(value),
                                value,
                                ESP_GATT_WRITE_TYPE_RSP,
                                ESP_GATT_AUTH_REQ_NONE);


    }
```

Another useful references:-

- [ESP write Char example](https://www.esp32.com/viewtopic.php?t=5792)